# React Route protection with HOC PrivateRoute component with asynchronous jwt token validation

Tags: reactjs, async-await, jwt, authorization, react-router-dom

I am not very experienced with React yet and have been trying to approach the problem of securing specific routes from authentication.

For this purpose, I need to implement a HOC component, specifically a "PrivateRoute" component.
Some main generalities:

1. I'm developing with React 17.0.2 and then react-router-dom 6.2.1
2. I need to verify the presence of the token on a Redis server (in the cloud) and validate it.

The project is divided into two "modules," one in React for the frontend and one in node js/express, which exposes the server-side logic.

In the frontend module, the routes are implemented as follows:

```
 return (<Router>
    <div className="App">
      <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top">
        <div className="container">
          <Link className="navbar-brand" to={"/"}>My Site</Link>
          <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
            <ul className="navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link className="nav-link" to={"/sign-in"}>Login</Link>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link className="nav-link" to={"/sign-up"}>Sign up</Link>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
          <Routes>
            <Route exact path='/' element={<PrivateRoute><Home /></PrivateRoute>} />
            <Route path="/sign-in" element={<Login />} />
            <Route path="/sign-up" element={<SignUp />} />
            <Route path="*" Component={<Login/>} status={403}/>
          </Routes>
    </div></Router>
```

As you can see, for example, I want the Home component to be protected, and therefore I implement the PrivateRoute component with which I wrap the Home component.

The implementation of the PrivateRoute component must validate any jwt token present in localStorage, passing it to an HTTP validation service exposed by the node/express module. The token is sent to the http service by passing the Authorization Bearer header.

The logic of retrieving from the localStorage and sending to the validation service is implemented with a useEffect (() => {}, []). Inside it is defined async function, so you can make the axios call with await. The function is always called from the body of useEffect. However, I cannot understand why updating the state variable created with useState seems not to update correctly (synchronization problem?). This does not seem to trigger the rendering update if the Home component is validated correctly (in the ternary operator, home is represented by props.children), rather than redirecting to the login page.

Below I report the implementation of the PrivateRoute:

```
export const PrivateRoute = (props) => {
    console.log('props',props);
    const [tokenValid, setTokenValid] = useState('');
    useEffect(() => {
        const checkRedisToken = async () => {
            console.log('Access localStorage');
            const ni_token = localStorage.getItem('ni_token');
            console.log('Returned localStorage');
            const config = { headers: { 'Authorization': `Bearer ${ni_token}` } };
            console.log('Call axios');
            const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/identity/verifytoken', config);
            const data = response.data;
            console.log('After axios ', data);   
            setTokenValid(response.data);
    
        }
        checkRedisToken();
        console.log('tokenValid', tokenValid);
    }, []);
 
    return (
        tokenValid !== '' ?
            props.children :
            <Navigate to="/sign-in" />
    )
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help in understanding my mistakes.

Thank you so much

Comment: `console.log('tokenValid', tokenValid);` will not log the new `tokenValid` value, because React state update is not immediate. Also `checkRedisToken` is `async`, and you're not awaiting on it. But the state should still update and the component should re-render. It could be helpful if you post the console output.

Comment: @tromgy thank you for your reply. Yes, you are right. The call is asynchronous, so I do not see the log valued. However, I would have expected a new re-rendering. In the meantime, reading some similar posts, I changed the code by introducing an intermediate state, which seems to work. How can I share the code and maybe comment on it together? Do I answer in my first place?

Comment: You can try to make a minimal reproducible example in codesandbox/stackblitz, etc. As we both agree the render still should take place whenever the `tokenValid` state is set.

Comment: Hi @tromgy,
For brevity, I will reply to my first post with what is currently my solution. The solution is the result of research on the web and some previous similar posts.
It would be helpful for me to discuss the solution to explain the logic and operation of React, even those who eventually find themselves reading this message thread in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I try to describe the solution I have adopted. The solution is the result of the reading of similar posts previously published and of readings scattered on the web.
As noted by @tromgy the problem of my first implementation is caused by the asynchronous call to the endpoint / identity / verifytoken.
The flow of execution, after the call, continues (waiting for a result) and the tokenValid state variable, even if set, seems not to be immediately detected by React and a new rendering is not invoked.

The correct solution seems to be to add an additional "loadingComplete" state.

The "loadingComplete" state seems to handle the stages where the component is not or is mounted waiting for the authenticated state to be ready and set as well.

The declaration of the routes has remained unchanged and for the sake of simplicity I show the code fragment below:

```
function App() {
  return (<Router>
    <div className="App">
      <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top">
        <div className="container">
          <Link className="navbar-brand" to={"/"}>My Site</Link>
          <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
            <ul className="navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link className="nav-link" to={"/sign-in"}>Login</Link>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link className="nav-link" to={"/sign-up"}>Sign up</Link>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
          <Routes>
            <Route exact path='/' element={<PrivateRoute><Home /></PrivateRoute>} />
            <Route path="/sign-in" element={<Login />} />
            <Route path="/sign-up" element={<SignUp />} />
            <Route path="*" Component={<Login/>} status={403}/>
          </Routes>
    </div></Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

As mentioned, the changes made to the PrivateRoute component are quite substantial. Before giving a brief description below, I report the new implementation below:

```
    export const PrivateRoute = (props) => {
        console.log('props', props);
        const [authenticated, setAuthenticated] = useState(null);
        const [loadingComplete, setLoadingComplete] = useState(false);
        useEffect(() => {
            const ni_token = localStorage.getItem('ni_token');
            const isLogin = async (ni_token) => {
                console.log('isLogin');
                try {
                    const config = { headers: { 'Authorization': `Bearer ${ni_token}` } };
                    const result = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/identity/verifytoken', config);
                    setAuthenticated(result.data);
                } catch (e) {
                    console.log(e);
                }
                setLoadingComplete(true);
            }
            isLogin(ni_token);
    
        }, []);
    
    
    
    
        if(loadingComplete){
            console.log('Completed', authenticated);
            return (authenticated === 'Verify Token Respone' ?
            props.children :
            <Navigate to="/sign-in" />)
        }else {
            console.log('Loading...');
            return (<div> Loading...</div>)
        }
}
```

As you can see the useEffect with empty dependency array, so that the passed function is only executed once.

On the first call to the web application root we observe the execution of console.log ('props', props).
Immediately thereafter, the console.log trace shows ('Loading ...').
Immediately after, the "isLogin" log appears, in fact useEffect calls isLogin (ni_token). At this moment the asynchronous http call is made to the endpoint "/ identity / verifytoken" in charge of validating the token. At the first access to the frontend (http: // localhost: 3000) there is no token and the endpoint returns an http 403 (Forbidden) status. The authenticated state variable is not changed and its value remains "null", but lodingComplete is set to "true" causing <Navigate to = "sign-in /> to be returned, ie the redirect to the login page.
As you can see, the change in state determines the rendering of the component, the "props" log and the "Completed null" log reappear.

Below you can find what is logged at first access:

props Object
Loading ...
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
props Object
Completed null

Some thougths for further deepening about not so clear aspects: if I do not misinterpret, at the new rendering the stream passes again through console.log ('props', props) and obviously react does not re-execute the useStates? Otherwise loadingComplete would be false again and would render  Loading  while as expected it goes through redirection to the login component. Is my interpretation correct?

If I finally log in and a positive authentication happens, the flow highlighted with the logs executed with console.log is the following:

props {children: {…}}
Loading ...
isLogin
props {children: {…}}
Loading ...
props {children: {…}}
Completed Verify Token Respone

If I'm not wrong, the re-rendering is done twice in addition to the first one. But there is something I can't quite understand. The useEffect is performed (log isLogin) the asynchronous http call is performed and setAuthenticated will be performed later the flow of execution certainly goes through setLoadingComplete (true) at this point I expect a re-rendering but contrary to what I expect I still see the "Loading" log ... But on the other hand if this is not the case it should still redirect to the Login component. Eventually, the "Completed Verify Token Respone" log appears at the setAuthenticated setting.

I'm still a bit puzzled who helps me understand what I see and what is happening? I hope this post can be useful to learn more about the mechanisms and functioning of React and of this specific need.

Comment: "react does not re-execute the useStates". That is not completely correct. On the _first_ execution the state is set to the _initial_ state that is passed as an argument to `useState`, but on subsequent renders `useState` actually returns the _current_ state.

Comment: And in your second sequence what happens is the component renders the first time with `loadingComplete` being `false` (initial), then the callback in `useEffect` is exectued, you get "isLogin" in the console, then the async axios call is scheduled, but the rendering continues, and it's still in the "loading" state, and finally the axios call is completed and the two states are set and it's re-rendered.

Comment: Hi @tromgy,
Thanks for your answers.
Deepening, also thanks to your considerations,
in the useEffect callback I added a couple of console logs: c onsole.log ('Before setAuthenticated ...'); setAuthenticated (result.data); and console.log ('Before setLoadingComple ...'); setLoadingComplete (true);. From the log sequence we observe at the first execution of the callback the execution stack is stopped at setAuthenticated and a new rendering is triggered. At that point, the stack is resumed, and the latest update loadingCompleted. Does it have anything to do with managing the cycle of events?

Comment: Once the `awat` on axios is done, both `setAuthenticated` and `setLoadingComplete` should execute in sequence. I would add something like `console.log(\`Rendering with: authenticated ${authenticated}, loadingComplete: ${loadingComplete}\`);` somewhere in the body of the main `PrivateRoute` function, e.g. just before `useEffect`. That should give your a clear picture on when rendering takes places and with what states.

Comment: @tromgy,I share the code and the new logs with a short link http://tny.im/paste.php?viewid=NjFkZjI5NWEyODU4MDIuNTY0Mjg3NzM=
Notice the call to the setIsAuthenticated function passed by the parent component (App.js). This call is used to change the status of the navigation bar after a successful login.
You can find the sequence of the logs at the following short link:
http://tny.im/paste.php?viewid=NjFkZjJhZTE3ZmNlNzYuMDk4NzcxODI=
As you can see, the rendering is done three times. Maybe because the setIsAuthenticated call forces the parent to be re-rendered? Thanks so much

Comment: Yes, you're correct. The rendering is done 3 times because the 3 states are set (in this sequence): `authenticated`, `isAuthenticated` (on the parent), `loadingComplete`. Setting state on the parent will cause children to re-render.

Comment: A question springs to mind. Does this approach cause a performance problem? To optimize, reduce re-renderings, would it be appropriate to transform the "authenticated" and "loadingComplete" state variables into an object? Eg. globalState = {autenticated: true, loadingComplete: true} and replace the two calls to setAutenticated and setLoadingComplet with a single call to setGlobalState? In this case, would I have two re-renders instead of three? Do you agree? Thank you

Comment: Yes, it would always make sense to minimize re-renders. In your case I think the `authenticated` state inside this `PrivateRoute` component is redundant, because you have the same state managed by its parent -- you pass `setIsAuthenticated` as a prop. So, you can also pass the parent state as well and use that in this child component instead of its own `authenticated`/`setAuthtenticated`

Comment: @tromgy I hadn’t thought about it. I think yours is a good idea. I will try to change the code again, even with this last thought. It was helpful and pleasant to confront you. Thank you